# How to check if an array of characters is a valid integer >= 1 in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I don't know the size of the array and using isdigit(array[i]) for every element i < sizeof(array) doesn't seem to work correctly.

I am trying to:

Check that every char is a digit.

Convert the string to int.

Check that it is > 0

```
int all_digits(char *string){

    short i;
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(string); i++){

        if (!isdigit(string[i])){
            //Non-digit found.
            return 1;           
        }

    }
    //All of them are digits.
    return 0;
}
```

The first part is the one that I can't get.

Comment: This will certainly not work if `array` is a pointer

Comment: Please clarify 1) I don't know the size of the array 2) doesn't seem to work correctly

Comment: I added my function.

Comment: --> `for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = strlen(string);
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
```

`sizeof(pointer)` is not same as `sizeof(array)`

You need to pass a valid string which is a null terminated string else `strlen()` might crash.

**Edits:**

Alternatively you can have

```
for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Comment: Unnecessary calculating `strlen` on each loop iteration. Calculate the length once, then use it: `int len=strlen(string); for(i=0; i<len; i++){...}` However the test for `string[i] != 0` is simpler.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes you are 100% right. I myslef have suggested the same in many of the answers . Check the edits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `string` is of type `char *`. `sizeof(string)` will give you the size of a `char *`, not the array.

You need to pass the size of the array explicitly, using another paramter to `all_digits()` function and use that value in `for` loop condition checking.

Maybe something like this

```
int all_digits(char *string, int size){

    short i;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++){

        if (!isdigit(string[i])){
            //Non-digit found.
            return 1;           
        }

    }
    //All of them are digits.
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Specifically in case of a `char *`, a better, smaller and cleaner approach to this can be achieved using `strlen()` [assuming proper aguments passed], which will give you the length of the supplied *string*.

Comment: @Gopi Very True, that's what I added in my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you cannot get the correct length using the `sizeof` function.

`sizeof` function will give you the size of the given data type. You can use the
`strlen` function.

While using the `strlen` you have to manage the following,

Consider in your string in last there is no null value you didn't get the correct value of the string length. For this you have to send the size of that array as a another parameter or you have to place the null value in the last value of the a string.

Then you can get that easily.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate along the string, testing every character:

```
int all_digits(char *string){
    if( *string == 0)              // empty string - wrong
         return 1;

    for( ; *string != 0; string++) // scan the string till its end (a zero byte (char)0)
        if (!isdigit(*string))     // test for a digit
            return 1;              // not a digit - return

    return 0;                      // all characters are digits
}
```

However that only tests if the string consists of digits and does not make you any closer to determining its numerical value...